Prove that a translation is (or is not) essentially surjective
Let $L_1$ be a first-order language with only one extralogical symbol, i.e. a unary predicate $Px$.
Let $L_2$ be a first-order language with only one extralogical symbol, i.e. a binary predicate $Rxy$.
Let $T_1$ be the empty theory, i.e. $T_1= \emptyset$.
Let $T_2$ be a theory that just says that $R$ is symmetric: $T_2 = \{\forall x\forall y (Rxy \rightarrow Ryx) \}$.
Let $f$ be a translation from $L_1$ to $L_2$ that maps "$P$" to "$\exists z Rxz$" (as usual, the translation commutes with the logical operators and the quantifiers).
A translation $f: T_1 \to T_2$ is essentially surjective just in case, for all formulae $\psi \in L(T_2)$ there is a formula $\phi \in L(T_1)$ such that $T_2 \vdash \psi \leftrightarrow f(\phi) $.
Is $f$ as defined above essentially surjective? (This is the exercise 4.5.24 from Hans Halvorson's The Logic in Philosophy of Science). To record the exercise in its original form:

Let $\Sigma =\{p\}$, where $p$ is a unary predicate, and let
$\Sigma'=\{r\}$, where $r$ is a binary relation. Let $T$ be the empty
theory in $\Sigma$, and let $T'$ be the theory in $\Sigma'$ that says
that $r$ is symmetric, i.e., $r(x,y)\rightarrow r(y,x)$. Let
$F:\Sigma\rightarrow\Sigma'$ be the reconstrual that takes $p$ to
$\exists zr(x,z)$. Is $F$ essentially surjective?


What have you tried?

@JeanAbouSamra I read that if $f$ is essentially surjective, then the functor $f^*: Mod(T_2) \mapsto Mod (T_1)$ induced by $f$ which goes from models of $T_1$ to models of $T_2$ is full. However, I was looking for a more syntactic way to prove this...

That's great context to add to the question (rather than a comment). Can you solve the problem using the fullness criterion, or not? Do you have a guess of an $L_2$-formula that is not equivalent to the translation of an $L_1$-formula?

No, the translation is not essentially surjective. For example, $R(x,y)$ is not $T_2$-equivalent to any formula in the image of $f$.
Here is one way to prove this: Let $M$ be the $L_2$-structure with domain $\{a,b,c\}$ and $R^M = \{(a,b),(b,a),(b,c),(c,b)\}$, so $M\models T_2$. The translation $f\colon T_1\to T_2$ allows us to view $M$ as a model of $T_1$. Since every element of $M$ satisfies $\exists z\, R(x,z)$, we have $P^M = \{a,b,c\}$. Note that the function $\sigma\colon M\to M$ fixing $a$ and transposing $b$ and $c$ is an automorphism of $(M,P^M)$. Thus $\sigma$ preserves the truth of $f(\varphi)$ for all $L_1$-formulas $\varphi$. But $\sigma$ does not preserve the truth of $R(x,y)$, since $M\models R(a,b)$ but $M\not\models R(a,c)$. Thus $R(x,y)$ is not equivalent to any formula of the form $f(\varphi)$ in $M$, and therefore not provably from $T_2$ either.
This argument is a special case of the fullness criterion you mentioned in the comments: The automorphism group of $(M,R^M)$ is a proper subgroup of the automorphism group of $(M,P^M)$, violating fullness.
If you want a more syntactic approach, you could proceed as follows. Show by induction on the structure of formulas that in any fixed $L_1$-structure, every $L_1$-formula is equivalent to a boolean combination of quantifier-free formulas. A purely syntactic formulation is that every complete $L_1$-theory has quantifier-elimination, or that every $L_1$-formula is equivalent to a boolean combination of sentences and quantifier-free formulas. In particular, for any $L_1$-formula $\varphi(x,y)$, the set defined by $f(\varphi(x,y))$ in an $L_2$-structure $M$ is a boolean combination of sets of the form $P\times M$, $M\times P$, and the diagonal $\Delta$. Now exhibit an $L_2$-structure in which the interpretation of $R$ does not have this form.

There are also $L_2$-sentences which are not $T_2$-equivalent to any sentence in the image of $f$. I find this argument even a bit more transparent than the automorphism argument above.
Consider the $L_2$-sentence $\psi\colon \forall x\, \forall y\, R(x,y)$. Let $M$ be the $L_2$-structure with domain $\{a,b\}$ and $R^M = M^2 = \{(a,a),(a,b), (b,a), (b,b)\}$. Let $M'$ be the $L_2$-structure with domain $\{a,b\}$ and $R^{M'} = \{(a,a),(b,b)\}$. Note that both $M$ and $M'$ are models of $T_2$, and $M\models \psi$, while $M'\models \lnot \psi$.
But applying our translation, $P^M = P^{M'} = \{a,b\}$, so for every $L_1$-sentence $\varphi$, $M\models f(\varphi)$ iff $M'\models f(\varphi)$. Thus $f(\varphi)$ is not $T_2$-equivalent to $\psi$.

I've added an answer; you may want to see it.

@TankutBeygu Thanks. I didn't understand your answer - see my comments below. In the meantime, I realized I could give an even shorter and more elementary argument that the translation is not essentially surjective, so I added to my answer.

I wish to suggest another answer for this particular exercise, not as an alternative to Kruckman's, but as an argument more suited to the supposed background of the book for which Kruckman's remains quite advanced.
I shall use $^{\ast}$ for $F$ and all those that fall into side of $\Sigma'$. Hence, a reconstrual $^{\ast}: T\rightarrow T^{\ast}$ is a translation of a $\Sigma$-theory $T$ into a $\Sigma^{\ast}$-theory $T^{\ast}$, for all $\Sigma$-sentences (i.e., closed formulas) $\phi$,
$$T\vdash\phi\implies T^{\ast}\vdash\phi^{\ast}$$
The given unary $\Sigma$-predicate is reconstrued as the $\Sigma^{\ast}$-formula $\exists zR(x,z)$, with one free variable as stipulated in the book. Hence, $P^{\ast}(x)$ is $\exists yR(x,y)$.
At the formula level, a $\Sigma$-formula $\phi$ that consists of $P(x)$ is translated as $\exists z(x = z\wedge\exists yR(z, y))$. Hence, $\theta^{\ast}$ is $\exists z(x = z\wedge\exists yR(z, y))$.
We recall that propositional connectives and predicate quantifiers are preserved across translation. So, for a $\Sigma$-sentence $\exists x P(x)$,
$$T\vdash\exists x P(x)\implies T^{\ast}\vdash\exists x\exists z(x = z\wedge\exists yR(z, y))$$
Now, we shall say that $^{\ast}$ is essentially surjective if for each $\Sigma^{\ast}$-formula $\psi$, there is a $\Sigma$-formula $\phi$ such that
$$T^{\ast}\vdash\psi\leftrightarrow\phi^{\ast}$$
(n.b. there is a print error in the book; it reads $T$ instead of $T'$).
There are various conceptions of intralogical translations (see, for example, the chapter X, Translations Between Logics, of the book
The Semantic Foundations of Logic volume 1: Propositional Logics by R.L. Epstein). Halvorson's conception preserves propositional connectives and predicate quantifiers. This is a passing remark in the book, however, explicitly stated in his 2015 paper co-authored with T. W. Barrett, "Glymour and Quine on Theoretical Equivalence":

[S]uppose that $F\phi$ and $F\psi$ have already been defined for
$\Sigma_{1}$-formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$. Then we define the
$\Sigma_{2}$-formulas
$F(\neg\phi):=\neg F\phi$,
$F(\phi\wedge\psi):= F\phi\wedge F\psi$,
$F(\phi\rightarrow\psi):= F\phi\rightarrow F\psi$,
$F(\phi\vee\psi):= F\phi\vee F\psi$,
$F(\phi\leftrightarrow\psi):= F\phi\leftrightarrow F\psi$,
$F(\forall x\phi):=\forall xF\phi$, and
$F(\exists x\phi):=\exists xF\phi$.

Since $T$ is an empty theory, it deduces only validities. However, $T^{\ast}$ has to satisfy the binary symmetry relation, so we shall focus on it. In accordance with the prservation property, the counterpart of the formula $\forall x\forall y(R(x, y)\rightarrow R(y, x))$ is
$$\forall x\forall y(\exists z(x=z\wedge\exists uR(z, u))\rightarrow\exists z(y=z\wedge\exists uR(z, u)))$$
Hence,
$T^{\ast}\vdash\forall x\forall y(R(x, y)\rightarrow R(y, x))\leftrightarrow\forall x\forall y(\exists z(x=z\wedge\exists uR(z, u))\rightarrow\exists z(y=z\wedge\exists uR(z, u)))$
must hold.
When we do the instantiations and equality eliminations, we get
$$(R(a, b)\rightarrow R(b, a))\leftrightarrow(R(a, c)\rightarrow R(b, d))$$
From this statement, we can read off a model that makes the right-hand side of the material equivalence hold, but not the left-hand side; for instance,
$$R =\{(a, b), (b, a), (a, c), (c, a)\}$$
As a side note, it is remarkable that Halvorson talks in terms of signatures, not languages, for it is preferable in philosophical texts to take a language composed of a logical vocabulary and a non-logical vocabulary (viz., signature).

I agree with everything you wrote until "the counterpart of the formula... is...". After that, I don't follow your argument.  $\Sigma^$-sentences like $\psi\colon\forall x\forall y,(R(x,y)\to R(y,x)$ don't have  counterparts. The translation goes the other way, from $\Sigma$-formulas to $\Sigma^$-formulas. In fact, the sentence you wrote down, $\forall x\forall y(\exists z(x=z\wedge\exists uR(z, u))\rightarrow\exists z(y=z\wedge\exists uR(z, u)))$ is $f(\varphi)$, where $\varphi$ is $\forall x\forall y,(P(x)\to P(y))$.

But nothing in the definitions require $T^\vdash \psi\leftrightarrow f(\varphi)$ for this particular choice of $\varphi$! In fact, your $\psi$ (the sentence asserting symmetry of $R$) is $T^$-provably equivalent to something in the image of $f$. Take $\theta$ to be any validity (like $\forall x,(x=x)$). Then $T^\vdash \psi\leftrightarrow f(\theta)$, since $T^$ proves both $\psi$ and $f(\theta)$.
